# How would I use excel to generate a large update sql statement?

Tags: sql, excel

I know there's a way to have insert statements within excel. Is there one for update? so far I've managed to come up with my update statement in SQL, but I have 6000 rows to update:

> = "Update table    Set name = " & A1 & "    Where namefk = " & E2 & ""

Basically, I want the name and namefk to be populated with fields in my excel..but I can't seem to get it right. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output you're getting? It's hard to know what's wrong without some idea of what your actual data looks like.
`Where namefk='"&E2&"';"` is one possible adjustment to ensure you have quotes around strings.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
= "update table set name = '" & B1 & "' where namefk = '" & A1 & "'"
```

where column A1 has name fk & B1 have name
You can drag the formula to achieve query to update thousands of records :)
You can look into the link with the 
[Example excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwblgQJV0OfGTFozWm9wVGF3RWM/edit?usp=sharing)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

```
=CONCATENATE("update Site set SiteName='",D13,"' where Place='",A13,"' and Code='",B13,"'")
```

As per above we can make update query dynamically and if we make for one row after that we need to drag down, so automatically it will take column values.